# Perakim in Medresh Rabbah

Tags: midrash, statistics

How many perakim are there in Medresh Rabbah (including the Megillos)? I'm trying to figure out a schedule. [image: What is the Daled Called, if the Alef is called the Perek. And how many of those types of "paragraphs" are in all of Medresh Rabbah?]

Comment: Not talking about the big chapters. I'm talking about the chapters within the chapters. @DoubleAA

Comment: I don't know what that means. Please [edit] to clarify exactly what you need and why you need help finding it.

Comment: You see the Daled. What is that? If the Alef is a Perek, then what's the Daled? @DoubleAA

Comment: They’re called Simanim or Se’ifim, depending on who you ask. The larger chapters, as you call them, are called Parshios, as you can see clearly at the top of your picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Total number of subchapters = 3,362

**Broken down by book (and weekly portion)**

- Bereishit - 1,038

  - Bereishit - 264
  - Noach - 90
  - Lech Lecha - 105
  - Vayeira - 114
  - Chayei Sarah - 49
  - Toldot - 67
  - Vayeitzei - 87
  - Vayishlach - 87
  - Vayeishev - 59
  - Mikeitz - 35
  - Vayigash - 25
  - Vayechi - 56
- Shemot - 462

  - Shemot - 85
  - Va'eira - 46
  - Bo - 71
  - Beshalach - 67
  - Yitro - 24
  - Mishpatim - 50
  - Terumah - 17
  - Tetzaveh - 17
  - Ki Tisa - 60
  - Vayakhel - 12
  - Pekudei - 13
- Vayikra - 330

  - Vayikra - 56
  - Tzav - 28
  - Shemini - 19
  - Tazria - 18
  - Metzora - 27
  - Acharei Mot - 47
  - Kedoshim - 17
  - Emor - 74
  - Behar - 22
  - Bechukotai - 22
- Bamidbar - 444

  - Bamidbar - 81
  - Naso - 175
  - Beha'alotcha - 25
  - Shelach - 34
  - Korach - 23
  - Chukat - 33
  - Balak - 25
  - Pinchas - 25
  - Matot - 9
  - Masei - 14
- Devarim - 161

  - Devarim - 25
  - Va'etchanan - 37
  - Eikev - 17
  - Re'eh - 11
  - Shoftim - 15
  - Ki Teitzei - 14
  - Ki Tavo - 12
  - Nitzavim - 7
  - Vayeilech - 9
  - Ha'azinu - 4
  - Vezot Haberachah - 10
- Esther - 125
- Shir Hashirim - 221
- Ruth - 90
- Eichah - 185
- Kohelet - 306

The data is based on manually looking at the last subchapter of each chapter and entering that number into an Excel spreadsheet. All calculations were performed using Excel sum functions. It is always possible that I may have made some data entry errors, but I think the numbers are pretty accurate. The text I used is a 2014 edition of the Vilna Midrash Rabba.

Comment: You're a legend @alex

Answer (score 1):

I went over to [sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Midrash/Aggadic%20Midrash/Midrash%20Rabbah).org and started counting (I can't attest to their version or their breakdown...I'm just reporting):

Bereishit -- 100 sections
Sh'mot -- 52
Vayikra -- 37
B'midbar -- 23
D'varim -- 11
Shir Hashirim -- 8 parshiyot, 115 sections total
Rut -- 8
Ester -- 10
Kohelet -- 12 parshiyot, 217 total
Eicha -- 5

The total is 223 in the 5 books and 355 in the megilot for a sum of 578.

Comment: Thanks for that @rosends. Although I was looking to know how many sifim are in the entire Medresh.

Comment: well, Bereishit 1 has 15...