# How many words are there in the Zohar?

Tags: words, jewish-books, zohar, statistics

1. Zohar (with and w/o the Tikunei Zohar)
2. Tikkunei Zohar

Also is there a site/place that lists or
otherwise aids in wordcounts for different 
Jewish books /Seforim ?

TYVM

Comment: @kouty We’ve has this kind of question asked for [Midrash Rabbah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102168/) and the [Kitzur SA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97160/). Why should this be any different?

Comment: It is not different for me. I don't understand how this helps!

Comment: @kouty My opinion is that they’re all on topic. If you’re going to be voting this one as off-topic, at least vote to close the others as well.

Comment: It is not important for me to close I cancel my opinion

Comment: I believe the answer is 2 - "the Zohar"

Comment: @Yesh Tikva, May I suggest you go to http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/d_root__106_kabala.html and count each section and then come back to us with an answer.

Comment: @Danny it's not Bitul Tora?

Comment: @JoshuaPearl Well aren't you sehr klug ;)

Comment: @kouty - for me and you, it is Bitul Torah. If Yesh-Tikva needs this information then for him it isn't. (That's why I didn't go counting for him.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Right!

Comment: You guys are all hilarious so I did partially what you said I went to the website and downloaded the text file and used a character counter ;);) Tikkunei has about 148000 words  could be a little off since it includes  The sources (ie bamidbar 21 1 , Shir hashirim 2,2 etc.)

Comment: Zohar in Total (without Tikkunei but with Zohar Chadash) = Approx 1,128,000 words

Comment: @YeshTikva - then post that info as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I discuss word counts for different classical Jewish works here:
[Words of Wisdom: Word Counts of Classical Jewish Works](https://www.academia.edu/106385574/Words_of_Wisdom_Word_Counts_of_Classical_Jewish_Works) (requires registration).

Based on Bar-Ilan Responsa Project CD, the word count of the main body of
Zohar is **691,909**.
Including all the traditionally included works ('Zoharic literature' -
such as *Midrash HaNane'elam*, *Ra'aya Mahemna*, etc.  )
: **1,239,420**

For a more detailed breakdown, see the screenshot of Bar-Ilan Responsa Project CD that I cite in my blog [here](https://www.ezrabrand.com/p/word-counts-of-classical-jewish-works).

(Unfortunately the screenshot that I was sent was cut off, so I can't answer what the word count of *Tikunei Zohar* is.)